# How to get ipa file from build folder in iphone sdk 4.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need to share distribution build to my client. When I used Xcode 4.0 it was very easy to find it. But now I am not able to see where the build folder places in the application folder. Now I am using Xcode 4.3. And it is little confusing for me. Can you guys please tell me the steps to find it out.

Thank you,
Chandra.

Comment: Have you upgraded to Xcode 4 from Xcode 3? Xcode 4 has a radically different system of how to do distribution and submission.

Answer (score 3):

Connect your device

and

select `XCode-->product-->archive` then **ipa** file is generated in **organizer** then select your file and click on share and save,your ipa file is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your build settings in the xCode preferences.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 3, you build the binary with Ad Hoc code signing settings and navigate to `~ProjectPath/build/AdHoc.ProjectName`.

In Xcode 4, you have to "Archive" your binary. Then, open the organizer and select your app from the Archives menu. Once you've done that, choose the build of the app that ou want to share and click the "Share" button. Xcode 4 will prompt you to choose a codesigning certificate. This must match the one in your scheme. Once that is done, Xcode will ask you where to put it. Choose a location and then you will have answered your own question: The build is wherever you left it.